# How do I get parts of my concatenated strings back in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have two strings

```
 str1 = "E|DaphneBlake" 
 str2 = "8/27/2015"
```

which are concatenated to one.

```
 string str3 = String.Concat(str1,str2)
```

This produces an Output:

```
 "E|DaphneBlake8/27/2015"
```

Later, I am trying to retrieve the two strings back into two var.
I am using this code to do so:

```
public static string getFirst(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
int Start, End;
if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
{
    Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart);
    End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd);
    return strSource.Substring(Start, End);
}
else
{
    return "";
}
}


public static string getLast(string strSource, string strStart)
{
int Start, End;
if (strSource.Contains(strStart))
{
    Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart);
    End = strSource.LastIndexOf(strStart) + 1;
    return strSource.Substring(Start, End);
}
else
{
    return "";
}
}

string data = getFirst("E|DaphneBlake8/27/2015", "E|Daphne Blake8", "8/27/2015");
string data2 = getLast("E|DaphneBlake8/27/2015", "8/27/2015");
```

The getFirst works but the **getLast does not**. It gives me an error

```
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.Parameter name: length
```

Comment: Read the error: "Parameter name: **length**". You are passing the end position, not the length of the string you want.

Comment: You don't show a definition for `getAfter`. Is the call supposed to be to `getLast`?

Comment: @DeanOC , sorry corrected the question.

Comment: You could have read the error message in less time than it took to ask this question.  You will never improve if you do not figure out how to solve trivial problems by yourself.

Comment: I realise this is probably just an exercise, but it seems pointless. Why not store it in some kind of reasonable data structure?

Comment: You're asking for a substring starting at position 13 that's 14 characters long, which would require a string that's 27 characters long, but the one you provide is only 22. Perhaps something to do with the source string's length. Maybe the source's length minus the index of the matched position?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue as suggested by @Blorgbeard above.

```
public static string getAfter(string strSource, string strStart)
{
int Start, End;
if (strSource.Contains(strStart))
{
    Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart);
    End = strStart.Length;
    return strSource.Substring(Start, End);
}
else
{
    return "";
}
}
```

Comment: In this case, since you know you want until the end of the strSource string, you can just use strSource.Substring(Start);

Answer (score -2):

If you have an identifier which is at the end of string one or the beginning of string two then you can use string.Split ('your identifier')